# PendingIntent.getActivity with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT won't update intent's flags

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onNewIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Intent b = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        b.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pia = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, a, 0);
        PendingIntent pib = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, b, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        try {
            pib.send();
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

With above code, when Activity starts, instead of an "`onNewIntent`" toast pops up, a new MainActivity invoked, ignores `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

But if I change `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, problem solved.

Is this a bug of Android? I'm testing this on an emulator running Android Pie.

Is there any way to update PendingIntent's flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` this **only causes the "extras" in the `Intent` to be updated**. It does nothing to the `Intent` flags.

If you want to change the `Intent` flags, you need to either use 2 different `PendingIntent`s (by using different `requestCode`s, for example), or you need to cancel the existing `PendingIntent` and create a new one.

Comment: So, is this intended behavior? It feels awkward that we can't update Intent's flag directly while PendingIntent considers two intents with different flags are same.

Comment: Yes, this is intended behaviour. The `PendingIntent` might have been given to (or might be in use by) other applications, therefore you cannot modify the behaviour of the `Intent` (ie: change flags). This is by design.